# could not bring up Siebel servers

Tags: siebel

I am unable to bring up the Siebel Servers, even though Gateway Name Server is up and running.
Got the below error while starting the Siebel service.

---

### Services

### Windows could not start the Siebel Server [Ent_TPP_STG3_siebsrvr1] on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 2555922.

### OK

Also find the System event log:

The description for Event ID 7024 from source Service Control Manager cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

Siebel Server [Ent_TPP_STG3_siebsrvr1]
%%2555922

The locale specific resource for the desired message is not present

Please let me know the possible solutions on this.

Thanks in Advance!!.

Regards,
Umamahesh

Answer (score 0):

Check the Siebel log file:
E:\Siebel\8.1.1.14.0\ses\siebsrvr\log\SiebSrvr.log

You could have something like this in there:

```
    SBL-SVR-00026: Unable to allocate shared memory.
```

If so try this:
Start Powershell

```
    Get-Process -ProcessName "sieb*" | Stop-Process
```

Now try to restart the service again. This worked for me.